# How to retain login session in rest assured?

Tags: rest, api, postman, rest-assured

Following is the Login Test case:

```
@Test
public void loginTest() {     
   given(). contentType( "application/json").  
    with(). body("{\"requesttype\":\"login\",\"mobile\":\"123456789\",\"password\":\"randompass\"}").when().post("https://m.abcopmany.com/application/svcwebservice.php").
   then(). assertThat().statusCode(200).  and().log().all();   }
```

Now I want to write another test case `ctiyListTest()` with the following body but it doesn't give the desired output as the login session from the `loginTest()` is not stored?

```
@Test
public void ctiyListTest() {      
    given().body({\"requesttype\":\"getcitylist\"}").when().post("https://m.abcopmany.com/application/svcwebservice.php").then().log().all();}
```

Comment: show what error you getting after after executing code? there must be some token which you need to pass with each request

Comment: I am passing the cookie for login request with all other request and it works.

Comment: you can post your answer to your question and accept it by click on tick so that others can get help from it

Answer (score 0):

I am passing the cookie for login request with all other request and it works